# How to send Listview data to MySQL database?

Tags: android, mysql, listview

I've been trying to pass the listview data to MySQL database but I'm not sure how to pass the data . I've been trying past few weeks but no luck so deleted the stuff and want to start again but not sure how to do it
here's my ListActivity code....
would appreciate if anyone can help me out? and I want to use the php scripts to connect to MySQL but I don't mind if anyone can come with easier solution for connecting to the database

Thanks

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;


public class ListActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);

        ListView lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.SmsList);

        if(fetchInbox()!=null){
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,fetchInbox());
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

    }
    public ArrayList<String> fetchInbox(){


        // Displays in array and grabs the sms from the sms folder and display them on the list view
        ArrayList<String> sms=new ArrayList<String>();


        // sms folder location
        Uri uriSms=Uri.parse("content://sms/");

        // created string for id, address ,date, body
        Cursor cursor=getContentResolver().query(uriSms, new String[]{"_id","address","date","body"}, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while(cursor.moveToNext()){

            // requires number and a message
            String address=cursor.getString(1);
            String body=cursor.getString(3);

            // displays Number : 5556/5554 and Message: any user messages.
            sms.add("Number: " +address+"\n Message: " +body);
        }
        return sms;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please tell first what your code should do step by step. Dont ask us to discover that from the code.

Comment: the code above allows me to see all the Number and Message in my Emulator/Phone but now I just simply want to store the Number and Message to MySQL automatically. everytime i receive any new message and stored in my list view, i want them to store to MySQL too. thanks

Comment: I see no code where you are trying to do that. Where is your MySQL database resided?

Comment: i already mentioned up there that i deleted them because it wasn't working for me, so need to put everything again

Comment: @greenapps I'm looking for the code too

Comment: did you get above code?